# Eigenvalue and system solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue associated to the constant vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ of the matrix A(t)  then $ x(t) = \exp(\int_0^t(\lambda(y)dy))v$ is a solution of the system $dx/dt = A(t)x$

I started by showing that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue associated to the matrix A then we have that $ x(t) = \exp(\int_0^t(\lambda(y)dy))v$ has a derivative equal to what is required.

Comment: I think you are missing some context. What's $A$? In your $x(t)$ expression, where is $t$ coming from? Is the $x(t)$ same as $x$ on the RHS of the definition of $x(t)$?

Comment: I have posted an update

Comment: Check if my edits are OK. If you already proved that the derivative of $x(t)$ with respect to $t$ is equal to $\lambda(t)x(t)$, you have already solved the problem

Comment: There is where I have the doubts. SInce $dx/dt = exp(\int_0^t(\lambda(y))dy) [\lambda(T)-\lambda(0)]*v =  \lambda(t)x(T)$

Comment: Where does the matrix A come to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ x(t) = \exp\left(\int_0^t\lambda(y)dy\right)v$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $t$ you get
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\lambda(t)\exp\left(\int_0^t\lambda(y)dy\right)v$$
We can use the fact that $\lambda(t)$ and the exponential are just some numbers (functions of $t$), to write
$$\begin{align}\frac{dx}{dt}&=\exp\left(\int_0^t\lambda(y)dy\right)\lambda(t)v\\&=\exp\left(\int_0^t\lambda(y)dy\right)A(t)v\\&=A(t)\exp\left(\int_0^t\lambda(y)dy\right)v\\&=A(t)x(t)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have that $dx/dt = exp(\int_0^t(\lambda(y)dy)[\lambda(t)]v=\lambda(t)*x(t)$.

Using the fact that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix A then you have that $dx/dt = A(t)x(t)$